# Connect Linux Ubuntu to network via Ethernet

Tags: 16.04, networking, ethernet, ip-address

I have a laptop with Linux Ubuntu 16.04 on it and I would like to have an Ethernet connection in order to access Internet. The problem is - in 95% of tries to connect via Ethernet, laptop takes VERY LONG time in order to get IP address. It can be about 5-10 minutes. In other 5% of tries laptop gets its address around 30 seconds.

That's my `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

That's my `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`:

```
# Configuration file for /sbin/dhclient, which is included in Debian's
#   dhcp3-client package.
#
# This is a sample configuration file for dhclient. See dhclient.conf's
#   man page for more information about the syntax of this file
#   and a more comprehensive list of the parameters understood by
#   dhclient.
#
# Normally, if the DHCP server provides reasonable information and does
#   not leave anything out (like the domain name, for example), then
#   few changes must be made to this file, if any.
#

option rfc3442-classless-static-routes code 121 = array of unsigned integer 8;

#send host-name "andare.fugue.com";
send host-name = gethostname();
#send dhcp-client-identifier 1:0:a0:24:ab:fb:9c;
#send dhcp-lease-time 3600;
#supersede domain-name "fugue.com home.vix.com";
#prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
    domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
    dhcp6.name-servers, dhcp6.domain-search,
    netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
    rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers,
    dhcp6.fqdn, dhcp6.sntp-servers;
#require subnet-mask, domain-name-servers;
timeout 60;
#retry 60;
#reboot 10;
#select-timeout 5;
#initial-interval 2;
#script "/etc/dhcp3/dhclient-script";
#media "-link0 -link1 -link2", "link0 link1";
#reject 192.33.137.209;

#alias {
#  interface "eth0";
#  fixed-address 192.5.5.213;
#  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.255;
#}

#lease {
#  interface "eth0";
#  fixed-address 192.33.137.200;
#  medium "link0 link1";
#  option host-name "andare.swiftmedia.com";
#  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
#  option broadcast-address 192.33.137.255;
#  option routers 192.33.137.250;
#  option domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
#  renew 2 2000/1/12 00:00:01;
#  rebind 2 2000/1/12 00:00:01;
#  expire 2 2000/1/12 00:00:01;
#}
```

And finally that's the output of `sudo ifup eth0` (My Ethernet interface is `eth0`):

```
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.3
Copyright 2004-2015 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/eth0/80:fa:5b:28:8a:a7
Sending on   LPF/eth0/80:fa:5b:28:8a:a7
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x9e33c853)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0x9e33c853)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13 (xid=0x9e33c853)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13 (xid=0x9e33c853)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13 (xid=0x9e33c853)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12 (xid=0x9e33c853)
No DHCPOFFERS received.
No working leases in persistent database - sleeping
```

And this is an output of `ping 192.168.1.1` which I launched right after `sudo ifup eth0` command:

```
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

After that line command hangs for around 7-10 minutes, and then:

```
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=297 ttl=64 time=0.542 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=298 ttl=64 time=0.446 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=299 ttl=64 time=0.320 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=300 ttl=64 time=0.459 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=301 ttl=64 time=0.444 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=302 ttl=64 time=0.409 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=303 ttl=64 time=0.519 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=304 ttl=64 time=0.454 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=305 ttl=64 time=0.501 ms
```

So, clearly all that time while ping was hanged laptop was getting an IP address. So my question is - what should I do in order to make my Linux Ubuntu to get an IP address as soon as possible? What obstacles could be here for the laptop?

P.S.: I switched a router. Situation hasn't changed so clearly there's something going on with my Linux setup. I'm pretty sure it can have an IP address much faster because sometimes Ethernet connection is ready in about 30 seconds which is feasible for me.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**Addition:**

Here's an output from `sudo lshw -c network` command:

```
*-network
      description: Ethernet interface
      product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
      vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
      physical id: 0.1
      bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
      logical name: eth0
      version: 12
      serial: 80:fa:5b:28:8a:a7
      size: 100Mbit/s
      capacity: 1Gbit/s
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
      configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
      resources: irq:16 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:df114000-df114fff memory:df110000-df113fff
 *-network DISABLED
      description: Wireless interface
      product: Wireless 8260
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 0
      bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
      logical name: wlan0
      version: 3a
      serial: a4:34:d9:53:52:37
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
      configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-29-generic firmware=22.391740.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
      resources: irq:128 memory:df000000-df001fff
```

Comment: Show me the output of `sudo lshw -c network`. Describe your network cable connections. Does your computer connect to a switch/hub/router/modem? Did this ever work, or is this a new problem? Does it work in Windows?

Comment: @heynnema thanks for your response! I'll give you an output shortly, having small technical problems now.. Computer connected to a router via Ethernet cable without any switch. Yes, same Ethernet cable is working absolutely fine on Windows

Comment: @heynnema Hello! I've added output of `sudo lshw -c network` you've asked for. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a gigabit router? You're only getting a 100Mb connection. Do you have DSL, or a cable modem? In the "Wired Connection" profile, what is your MTU, and is IPv6 enabled/disabled? Please answer ALL of these questions. Temporarily try connecting your ethernet cable directly from your computer to the DSL/cable modem, POWER OFF BOTH the modem and your computer, POWER ON the modem, wait 30 seconds, POWER ON the computer. Tell me if that's any better.

Comment: @heynnema what I can tell for now while I'm investigating all these questions that I changed `timeout` parameter to 5 and `retry` to 1 in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`and laptop is connecting in 20-30 seconds.

Comment: By tweaking with the timeout and retry parameters, all you did was to limit the time that it tries to get a proper connection. You still have a problem. Look at `ifconfig` and see. You should put `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` back to default, Same with `/etc/network/interfaces`,

Comment: @heynnema I understand what these parameters are for. But fact is fact - with such parameters Ethernet connection establishes literally 11 times faster (I time measured it). I just thought it's worth sharing :)

Comment: If you come here for help, instead of continuing to tweak the system on your own, you should follow the directions of your helper. You still haven't answered the basic questions that I asked 1/2 hour ago. How is anybody supposed to help you?

Comment: Gee, I'm following those, I have no idea whatsoever what made you think I'm not doing that :) I just thought that I found something worth sharing, that is all. MTU is 1500, IPv6 is enabled, router max lan speed I'm trying to find out now. I don't have Windows in my hands now so I need to figure out how to check it in Linux